# File 'MainViewController.swift' is part of module 'Charts'; ignoring import

Tags: swift, xcode, charts

First of all thanks in advance for any help I could receive, this would be SO helpful ! :)

I have imported my Charts project with Cocoapods in my project and I created a UIView on a ViewController: 
[https://ibb.co/427MQrJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EZRu.png)

The grey at the bottom is a UIView using Charts.

The UIView gets the Charts Module and the PieChartViewClass autocompletes itself. So Charts is loaded efficiently.

Here is the error I get though, when importing "Charts" into my UIViewController code (containing the UIView) as follows :

```
import Charts
```

And here is the warning I get :

> File 'MainViewController.swift' is part of module 'Charts'; ignoring
>   import

Do you have any ideas of how that could be helped ? Thanks in advance for your help

Thanks in advance for any of your help guys,
Have a great day!

Comment: what is your project name?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My project name is "PO-Scorad"

Comment: I think that you have added your file to multiple targets by mistake. Check the target membership of `MainViewController.swift`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sulthan, I did it again with another project, without doing anything twice or wrong and now it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

May your project's name is the same name of what you want to import in this case may Charts , to ssolve it change the project name.